# Akka cluster: why don't I receive a Reachable event?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remoting

I have two nodes in a Akka cluster.

I subscribe to all `ClusterDomainEvent` of the cluster with:

```
cluster.subscribe(
    self,
    InitialStateAsEvents,
    classOf[ClusterDomainEvent])
```

When one of the two nodes is down, I receive a `Unreachable` event and I start to receive some logs every few seconds that warn me as following:

```
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2554] has failed
```

When the down node come back, the logs stop, so it is detected that the node is reachable again but I still don't get a `ReachableMember` event.

What am I missing? Why should I do in order to receive this cluster event?

Answer (score 0):

The way of doing it is to subscribe to cluster events with `classOf[ReachabilityEvent]`

So

```
cluster.subscribe(
  self,
  InitialStateAsEvents,
  classOf[MemberEvent],
  classOf[ReachabilityEvent])
```

Comment: That's strange, from Akka code I can see, that `ClusterDomainEvent` includes `ReachabilityEvent` (`sealed trait ReachabilityEvent extends ClusterDomainEvent`). That shouldn't have made a difference.